# Have to do Owin Authentication signout twice when using Chrome

Tags: authentication, owin, ws-federation

We are using Owin WsFederation to authenticate to Azure AD and to log-off we just call  HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut().
This works with IE the first time but we have to log off twice when using Chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried clearing out the AspNet cookie prior to calling SignOut? That  works for me.